# can't receive values from spring cloud config server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, github, spring-cloud-config

Using @Value(${fanout.exchange}) annotation failed to init while using a spring-cloud-config server with Github repo.
I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queue' defined in class path resource [com/eloomina/dataCollector/rabbitMQ/RabbitConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue]: Factory method 'queue' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.rabbitConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'fanout.exchange' in value "${fanout.exchange}"
```

both classes have spring-cloud-config on their pom.xml. configServer is annotated with @EnableConfigServer . my file in the github repo is named dataCollector.properties

RabbitConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class RabbitConfiguration {
    @Value("${fanout.exchange}")
    private String rawDataExchange;
    @Value("${queue.name}")
    private String queueName;
    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, true);
    }
    @Bean
    FanoutExchange exchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange(rawDataExchange);
    }
    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, FanoutExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange);
    }
}
```

my config server application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.application.name=configServer
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/eLoomina/configFiles
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=xxxxxx
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=xxxxxx
```

my client bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.application.name=dataCollector 
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
management.security.enabled=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

github repo contain one file: dataCollector.properties :

s

```
pring.devtools.restart.enabled = false

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka


server.port=8081
spring.application.name=dataCollector

##MONGO:
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=accounts



management.server.port: 9001

## RABBITMQ
queue.name: rawDataQueue
fanout.exchange: rawdata-exchange
spring.rabbitmq.host: localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port: 5672
spring.rabbitmq.username: guest
spring.rabbitmq.password: guest

##LOGGING:
logging.file=dataCollector.log
```

any ideas why the dataCollector service won't get fanout.exchange from the config server?

Answer (score 0):

Is your file loaded in spring context? Can you see the file in the log something like below:

> INFO 1234 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration :Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='demoService',
>   propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'},
>   MapPropertySource
>   {name='https://github.com/demo-configuration/application.properties'}]}

Comment: i can access localhost:8888/dataCollector/default. do you mean in my config server? or in the client? (dataCollector)?

Comment: I meant in the client when you boot up your client is the config file loaded. Because unless the config file is loaded  @Value cannot bind the field to a property as the property will not be available in spring context.

Comment: I can't see the file in the log of the client

Comment: I guess then the issue is in fetching the file from config server. Can you once move the configuration-file locally in the client's resources directory and include in spring context, then see if it works? If it does, the issue is related to the config server.

Comment: Also, try to move all config properties to bootstrap.properties instead of application.properties
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/eLoomina/configFiles
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=xxxxxx
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=xxxxxx

Comment: it does load the other parameters from the remote config server